# Make an array from array of array of objects with same property

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have an javascript array and it contains another array of objects. Now I want to do sum of the field of objects having same symbol key.
How to do that ?

The array I have

```
let orders = [
    {
        "_id": "6c18cea3-7d37-4f85-b369-abf03e7ff873",
        "subOrders": [
            {
                "symbol": "SUZ",
                "fulfilledQty": "49.333991119"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "FSLR",
                "fulfilledQty": "2.895864705"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "acf75fcb-496a-4825-b7bc-cef60556fe49",
        "subOrders": [
            {
                "symbol": "FSLR",
                "fulfilledQty": "1"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "SUZ",
                "fulfilledQty": "1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "e32041a1-17f0-44c4-9fc4-4619e0507392",
        "subOrders": [
            {
                "symbol": "SUZ",
                "fulfilledQty": "8.751458576"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "FSLR",
                "fulfilledQty": "0.587774294"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The array I want from above array

```
[
    {
        "symbol": "FSLR",
        "fulfilledQty": "4.483638999"
    },
    {
        "symbol": "SUZ",
        "fulfilledQty": "59.085449695"
    }
]
```

So I want to the sum of `fulfilledQty` of same `symbol`

I tried this

```
let totalOrder = {};
   for(let order of orders){
      for(subOrder of order.subOrders){
         totalOrder[subOrder.symbol] = totalOrder[subOrder.symbol] ? 
            parseFloat(totalOrder[subOrder.symbol]) + 
            parseFloat(subOrder.fulfilledQty) : 
            parseFloat(subOrder.fulfilledQty);
         }
}
```

That gives me this object

```
{SUZ: "59.085449695", FSLR: "4.483638999"}
```

then I will convert it to array.
Because Inside inner for loop I will have to put another loop to compare the symbols So this will not iterate each time to compare symbols
That can be achieved using the loops but do so I will have to iterate the arrays too many times
Is there any simpler way to do so ?

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. You only iterate through the arrays once. Since you need to visit every entry at least once, there is no simpler way to do this, just different ways of writing the same thing (as you see in the answers).

Comment: If you do not want to use javascript loops and If you are getting the orders array from mongodb then you can achieve this by mongodb aggregation as all the calculations will be done at mongo server.

Comment: @AbhishekGoswami Yes I am getting the array from mongodb

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `.reduce()` to sum up the qty by symbol, then map that into the desired array:

```js
const input = [
  {
    "_id": "6c18cea3-7d37-4f85-b369-abf03e7ff873",
    "subOrders": [
      { "symbol": "SUZ",  "fulfilledQty": "49.333991119" },
      { "symbol": "FSLR", "fulfilledQty": "2.895864705" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "acf75fcb-496a-4825-b7bc-cef60556fe49",
    "subOrders": [
      { "symbol": "FSLR", "fulfilledQty": "1" },
      { "symbol": "SUZ",  "fulfilledQty": "1" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "e32041a1-17f0-44c4-9fc4-4619e0507392",
    "subOrders": [
      { "symbol": "SUZ",  "fulfilledQty": "8.751458576" },
      { "symbol": "FSLR", "fulfilledQty": "0.587774294" }
    ]
  }
];
let sums = input.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  obj.subOrders.forEach(item => {
    let symbol = item.symbol;
    let qty = Number(item.fulfilledQty);
    if(!acc[symbol]) {
      acc[symbol] = qty;
    } else {
      acc[symbol] += qty;
    }
  });
  return acc;
}, {});
let result = Object.keys(sums).sort().map(symbol => {
  return {
    symbol: symbol,
    fulfilledQty: sums[symbol].toString()
  };
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: So there will be so many loops and I have to iterate so many times

Comment: It's a fast O(2n), likely faster than the MongoDB aggregation

Comment: The orders array can increase upto the number of orders by user and in the orders document, there are atlease 15 fields and other 20 fields in subOrders. I have not included the other fields to simplify the question

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Array.flatMap()` and `Array.reduce()` to do it

```
let result = orders.flatMap(e => e.subOrders).reduce((a,{symbol,fulfilledQty}) => {
  a[symbol] = a[symbol]??0
  a[symbol] += +fulfilledQty
  return a
},{})
console.log(result)
```

```js
let orders = [
    {
        "_id": "6c18cea3-7d37-4f85-b369-abf03e7ff873",
        "subOrders": [
            {
                "symbol": "SUZ",
                "fulfilledQty": "49.333991119"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "FSLR",
                "fulfilledQty": "2.895864705"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "acf75fcb-496a-4825-b7bc-cef60556fe49",
        "subOrders": [
            {
                "symbol": "FSLR",
                "fulfilledQty": "1"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "SUZ",
                "fulfilledQty": "1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "e32041a1-17f0-44c4-9fc4-4619e0507392",
        "subOrders": [
            {
                "symbol": "SUZ",
                "fulfilledQty": "8.751458576"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "FSLR",
                "fulfilledQty": "0.587774294"
            }
        ]
    }
]

let result = orders.flatMap(e => e.subOrders).reduce((a,{symbol,fulfilledQty}) => {
  a[symbol] = a[symbol]??0
  a[symbol] += +fulfilledQty
  return a
},{})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned you are getting the array from mongodb then you can make a aggregation pipeline.

```
              let aggregation = [
                    {
                      '$match': {
                         //Your query here
                       }
                    }, {
                      '$unwind': {
                        'path': '$subOrders'
                      }
                    }, {
                      '$group': {
                        '_id': '$symbol', 
                        'symbol': {'$first': "$symbol"},
                        'total': {
                          '$sum': {
                            '$toDouble': '$fulfilledQty'
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
```